# Cannot change macOS 10.13.4 screenshot location

Tags: macos, screenshot, macos-highsierra

I'm trying to change the location where my screenshots get saved to my Desktop and no matter what I try, they are always saved to my Documents folder.

Here's the way you're supposed to be able to change the location:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/; killall SystemUIServer
```

The problem is that issuing that command seems to do nothing at all. I've used it in the past on other macOS machines with success so I don't know what gives.

I tried changing the location to another folder outside of my home folder and I also tried opening up the permissions on the destination folder to 777. Nothing seems to change the save location. I'm sure this is something simple but I'm just not seeing it. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm running MacOS 10.13.4. The permission change was temporary and  on a folder that wasn't one of MacOS's system directories. Solid advice though, thanks for looking out!

Answer (score 2):

Eureka, I've figured this out. Turns out this is specific to the MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, which I am on.

When taking a screenshot, the Touch Bar provides a way to choose the screen capture location and all screenshots will go to the location selected on the Touch Bar instead of the location set in `com.apple.screencapture`. Choosing the desired save location on the Touch Bar allows you to save to the new location and whichever location you choose will be the default for your next screenshot.

You can override the location chosen on the Touch Bar (which only gives you a handful of pre-set options), but it seems like macOS always saves to the Touch Bar location UNLESS you specifically choose "Desktop" on the Touch Bar and ONLY THEN will your custom defaults location override the Touch Bar. Or at least that's what I saw in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

Just found that you can configure your own destination:
(Some option name may be various because I use Chinese UI instead of English and I simply guess the original wording)

1. Activate Screenshot.app from Application/Tools or LaunchPad/Others
2. Click "Options" menu on the right side of toolbar at bottom of screen->Save to...->Other destinations
3. Select your destination for screenshots, you'll also find your folder name at the right end of touchbar.
4. Your screenshots are saved to the new destination from now (old files were not moved). If you change destination from touchbar in the future, you'll need to do 1~3 again to get it back.